# Identify a specific process in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, command-line, activity-monitor, console

I'm writing a shell script that mimics the functionality of setting the menu bar date and time format via System Preferences in macOS Big Sur. The action of checking/unchecking the *24-Hour Time* option in *System Preferences > Language & Region > General* appears to restart a process, but I can't tell which one.

I'm certain it's none of the `Dock`, `SystemUIServer` or `cfrefsd` processes. I've tried identifying the process using the Activity Monitor and Console apps and `top` in Terminal, but I have little experience with these and am most likely missing something.

Is there a way to be able to identify processes that have been killed or (re-)started within a given time period, say the last 60 seconds.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards, Steve

Comment: Try killing `ControlCenter`

Comment: @Redarm Many, many thanks. That's exactly the process I was looking for. Can I ask, did you just happen to know that, was it trial and error or is there some sure-fire way of identifying the process?

Comment: I just stumbled over it, when ControlCenter crashed repeatedly.  If I could answer your question, I would.  Sorry.